# Image paths are not resolved within component that gets parameters from the url

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have a component that gets parameters via the url, and uses useParams(). In this component I want to display an image, but the image is not displayed.
When I disable the ability to send url parameters to this component, the image is displayed.
The image is in the public folder.

**Without sending params:**

```
//App.js
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/somePath' element={ <SomeComponent/>}/>
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>


//SomeComponent.js
    export default function SomeComponent() {
      return (
        <img src='butterfly.png'/>
      )
    }
```

**With parameters:**

```
//App.js     
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/somePath/:someParameter' element={ <SomeComponent/>}/>
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>


//SomeComponent.js
    export default function SomeComponent() {
        const { someParameter } = useParams();
      return (
        <img src='butterfly.png'/>
      )
    }
```

**Sandbox example**
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-colden-16rfb0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The only difference between the two is that `someParameter` would be undefined in the first example, and defined in the second. I see no reason for that to change rendering the image. Is this the complete code? Do you have a working code example that reproduces this issue? Have you ensured you've cleanly restarted your project between changes? If issue persists can you try creating a *running* codesandbox demo for us to inspect and debug live?

Comment: I edited the question and added a running codesandbox example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should

```
<img src='/butterfly.png'/>
```

if you don't add "/" your image URI will be : /somePath/:someParameter/butterfly.png', this is wrong